# why are outgoing text message bubbles colorful?

Tags: design-patterns, color, conventions

Why are speech bubbles either blue or green for outgoing messages and not for incoming messages?

For example, in whatsapp, the outgoing messages are green. In iMessage, they are blue. I don't think I've ever seen a messaging app where the outgoing message bubbles are grey and the incoming ones are coloured. Is there a reason for this?

Comment: Yes both questions discuss the same idea.

Comment: Some more insight about how it affects people - https://www.theverge.com/2019/5/15/18624681/apple-imessage-android-blue-green-bubble-color-meaning-whyd-you-push-that-button-podcast